# Should `typename T::value_type` fail to compile when it is meant to be rejected by a constraint that comes later in the definition?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

The following code:

```
#include <concepts>

template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
  template <std::convertible_to<typename T::value_type> U> requires requires { typename T::value_type; }
  void bar()
  {
  }

  template <typename U>
  void bar()
  {
  }
};

int main()
{
  auto foo = Foo<float> {};
  foo.bar<int>();
}
```

is rejected by GCC 11:

```
error: ‘float’ is not a class, struct, or union type
     8 |   void bar()
       |        ^~~
```

What I expected to happen was that the first definition of `bar` to be rejected due to an unsatisfied constraint and the second one to be selected. However, apparently when GCC tries to substitute `float` for `T` it fails to compile `typename T::value_type` before looking at the constraint. I can get the behaviour that I expected if I replace the definition with:

```
template <typename U> requires (requires { typename T::value_type; } && std::convertible_to<U, typename T::value_type>)
void bar()
{
}
```

which I find much less elegant.

Does the standard say that the first approach is illegal or is it a deficiency in the GCC implementation? If it's the former, is there a nicer way of writing this constraint (short of defining a new named concept like `convertible_to_value_type_of`)?

**Edit:** Just to clarify in the light of comments and the (now deleted) answer: I understand why this code would be rejected based on pre-C++20 rules. What I was getting at is that the addition of concepts to C++20 could have been an opportunity to relax the rules so that the compiler defers the verification of validity of something like `typename T::value_type` until it checks the constraints that might come in the rest of the definition. My question is really: were the rules relaxed in this manner?

Comment: What's wrong with defining a new concept though?

Comment: just replace T with float in your template and see what it yields then you understand the error and what is wrong (you can't apply :: to a non class/struct/union/namespace)

Comment: in your first template void bar ,the first occurrence of T::value_type is not a deduced thing and therefor not SFINAE'd away and thus an error.

Comment: I prefer the working version syntax, than your version. (it would be more questionable for `template <std::convertible_to<typename T::value_type> U> void bar();` with implicit requirements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard is quite clear that constraints are only substituted into [at the point of use or when needed for declaration matching](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.inst#17):

> The *type-constraints* and *requires-clause* of a template
> specialization or member function are not instantiated along with the
> specialization or function itself, even for a member function of a
> local class; substitution into the atomic constraints formed from them
> is instead performed as specified in [temp.constr.decl] and
> [temp.constr.atomic] when determining whether the constraints are
> satisfied or as specified in [temp.constr.decl] when comparing
> declarations.

This is a [GCC bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=100374). It appears that GCC does handle this correctly in a *requires-clause* so that can be a workaround:

```cpp
  template <class U>
      requires std::convertible_to<U, typename T::value_type>
  void bar() 
  {
  }
```